# create an .aar file without dependencies libs

Tags: android-studio, gradle, dependencies, aar

I'm developing an android library which contains an external 3rd party library (for example: dagger).
I want to publish an .aar file to maven which not contains the dagger library inside. How can I create .aar file that doesn't contain any 3rd party libraries and contains only my code.

Another question, publishing .jar file instead of .aar file can solve this issue but there are any disadvantages is this solution?

Comment: Jar can contain the resources files.